# meteor method returns external url, how to link to external url from client

Tags: url, meteor, methods, routes

I've got a button on my app dashboard that says "access e-learning portal".

Clicking that button calls a Meteor.method which queries the e-learning portal API to receive an access link (single sign on).

I've got this working fine.

What I can't work out is how to then send that link from the server to the client so I can redirect them to it. I just cannot wrap my head around synchronous, asynchronous, callbacks etc. I do not understand why the method doesn't just send the client its result. My result is undefined

SO from the users point of view: click button -> e-learning portal opens in new tab (or same tab whatever)

from apps point of view: click button -> template.event -> meteor.call ->run server method -> retrieve URL (I've successfully got this far) -> send user to retrieved url (e.g) http://www.google.com

Here's my code:

Event:

```
Template.dashboard.events({
  'click #lmsAccess': function(e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();

    Meteor.call('lmsLink', function(error, result) {
      if(error) {
        console.log(error.reason);
        return;
      }
      console.log(result); //returns as undefined
    });

  }
});
```

Method

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {

  Meteor.methods({
    'lmsLink': function () {
      //removed all my irrelevant variables from here for stack question

      HTTP.call( verb, 'http://sandbox.wceaapi.org/'+ endPoint, {
        headers: {
            "Request-Time": timeStamp,
            "Api-Key": key,
            "Signature": hash
          }
      }, function( error, response ) {
        if ( error ) {
          console.log( error );
        } else {
          console.log( response );
          var result = JSON.parse(response.content);
          var accessLink = result.records.accessLink;
          console.log(accessLink);
          return accessLink;
        }
      });
    }// end lmsLink
  });//end method
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the url client side (via the method callback function) you can simply use

```
location.href = returnedUrlFromMethod;
```

This will redirect the user to that url.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. That definitely helps with my next step, but I maybe should have clarified that although my server console is logging the accessLink, I can't work out how to get it from the server to the client. Will update the original question

Comment: Hm, not 100% sure about that, but I think you have to use a pattern as described here: https://www.discovermeteor.com/patterns/5828399

Comment: Hey, I managed to get the futures working and it's all working now. 

Thanks for your help